# How to convert timestamp to numbers

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
Id      Types      Timestamp

1        A          2014-02-04 00:00:00
2        A          2014-02-05 00:00:00
1        A          2014-02-05 03:59:00 
3        C          2014-05-06 03:59:00
1        B          2014-02-04 03:00:00
2        D          2014-02-05 00:40:00
```

I would like the output to be like this:

```
Id     1       2        3          4          5           etc
1      A       B        A          C          D           ...
2      A       D        NULL       NULL       NULL
3      C       NULL     NULL       NULL       NULL
```

Is it possible to make time expresses the type's order.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Preliminary comments:

1. SQL can only return a predefined number of columns returned. IMHO, the best you can get is values concatenated in an array.
2. I have name your input table `MyTable` and renamed the column `Timestamp` to `MyTimestamp` to avoid conflict with the corresponding type's keyword.
3. You have put C and D in the 1 row of your output. I will treat it as a typo (they are not on ID = 1)

-

```
WITH RECURSIVE ConcatAndOrder(ID, MyResult, RowNumForOrder, RowCountForOrder) AS (
    SELECT ID, ARRAY[Type], RowNumForOrder, RowCountForOrder
    FROM IndexedTable
    WHERE RowNumForOrder = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT I.ID, MyResult || I.Type, I.RowNumForOrder, I.RowCountForOrder
    FROM IndexedTable I
    JOIN ConcatAndOrder C on I.ID = C.ID and I.RowNumForOrder = C.RowNumForOrder + 1
), IndexedTable(ID, Type, RowNumForOrder, RowCountForOrder) AS (
    SELECT ID, Type, 
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY MyTimestamp),
        count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT ID, MyResult
FROM ConcatAndOrder
WHERE RowNumForOrder = RowCountForOrder
ORDER BY ID
```